# C | Pointer doesnt give the value

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to do something easy, but i could find any solution.
I have an array, and I want to find an index, and update the pointer from a Function,
When Im trying to return the **Address of the index, and after it Print the Value at that index, I get nothing..
I hope you can Help me

```
int main()
{
    int array[]={3,2,3,4};
    int* pointer=NULL;
    doIT((int *)array,4,pointer);
    printf(" value of address %d",*pointer);
}
void doIT(int *p,int sizes,int** pointer){

    for(int i =0;i<sizes;i++)
    {

        if(*p==4)
        {
            printf("TT %d",*p);
            pointer=&p;
           // printf("\n  %d \n",pointer);
        }
        p++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `doIT((int*)array,4,pointer)` try `doIT((int*)array,4,&pointer)` and instead of `pointer=&p`, try `*pointer=p`.

Comment: Please pay attention to build warnings; they should be giving you a very clear hint.

Comment: it works! Am I suppose to do void doIT(int *p,int sizes,int* pointer) or **pointer as I did?

Comment: `doIT(int*,int,int**)` seems to be what you want.  By having a third `int**` argument, you're able to pass the address of `pointer` to `doIT` so that `doIT` can modify `pointer`.

Comment: What is the difference between the double **? Why i need double "Pointer?"

Comment: `int` is an integer type, `int*` is a pointer to an integer, and `int**` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer.  Given that you want your function to change `pointer` (an `int*`), you need to pass its address (the pointer to the pointer) to the function (i.e., `&pointer`) so that the function can dereference it to change it, hence the `*pointer=p`.

Comment: Thanks Mate!, When Im trying to do it with (Int *) its still working

Comment: The casting `(int*)array` is not required. Ana array name automatically decay to a pointer to the first value when passed as parameter in a function call. Simply write `doIT(array,4,&pointer)`. A pointer to an object in C is a variable as any other and its content is the address of the object to which it points to. If you want to change its value from a function you need a pointer to the address of it, the pointer variable, so you can write at that address and then find its value changed. You may want to read something about passing parameters by value and by reference (pointer to it in C).

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors: First, you have to call the function with

```
&pointer
```

and second, in the function body you have to set

```
*pointer=p;
```